# 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'setSizeGripEnabled'

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

using Pyside2 and command

```
pyside2-uic "untitled.ui" -o "gui.py"
```

I faced such exception

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow' object has no
attribute 'setSizeGripEnabled'
```

and did not find a solution in internet. Flag -x doesn't help. It answeres:

```
uic: Unknown option 'x'.
```

My main.py:

```
import sys  
from PySide2 import QtWidgets  
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile  
from gui import Ui_Dialog
        
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Ui_Dialog()
        w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ex.setupUi(w)
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gui.py:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        if not Dialog.objectName():
            Dialog.setObjectName(u"Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(511, 400)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        ...
        Dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(Dialog)
        ...

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Currency Converter", None))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText("")
        ...
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My window object in QT Designer is called "Dialog" and in 'gui.py' made from .ui file I have such line:

```
Dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
```

that cuses a problem.
But **if we just comment this line - UI interface starts to work!**

Answer (score 3):

Your code `w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` is not correct

try change your code to `w = QtWidgets.QDialog()`

I had the same error, but I solved it with this code.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog

from resources.gui import Ui_notes

class Window(QDialog, Ui_notes):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     window = Window()
     window.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```